# How to print records in a table with pagination in angular 6.(All the records not only the current page)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

I am fetching records from backend and precessing it on the UI in  a table with pagination .

I also have one print button which  need to print all the records in the table .

But when i am printing it is printing only the page i am in .

my.ts file.

```
onPreviewClick(e){
     console.log(e);
    let printContents = document.getElementById(e).innerHTML;
    // var printContents = this. filteredDataAfterDate;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     console.log(e, printContents, originalContents);

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
  }
```

HTML :

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>

<button (click)='omProceedClick($event)'type=”button”>Button</button>
<div  >
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let a of totalDate; let index = index"> {{ a }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="printareaDiv">
<table style="width:80%" id="printarea">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>ApplicationStatus</th> 
    <th>SubmittedBy</th>
  </tr>
  <tr  *ngFor="let a of filteredDataAfterDate | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 1, currentPage: p }; let index = index">
    <td>{{a.Date}}</td>
    <td>{{a.ApplicationStatus}}</td> 
    <td>{{a.SubmittedBy}}</td>

  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Print Preview" class="btn" (click)='onPreviewClick("printareaDiv")'/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML you are passing 'printareaDiv' as parameter to onPreviewClick() function and taking this parameter as Id to find the HTML element. But in your HTML there is no element with id 'printareaDiv'. The table you are referring is having different id which is 'printarea'.

Instead of this you can write like this :

```
function onPreview(e){
const printContents = document.getElementById(e).innerHTML
  const WindowObject = window.open('','PrintWindow','width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes'
  );
  const htmlData = `<html><body>${printContents}</body></html>`;

  WindowObject.document.writeln(htmlData);
  WindowObject.document.close();
  WindowObject.focus();
  setTimeout(() => {
    WindowObject.close();
  }, 0.5);
};
}
```

To print all table data ignoring pagination, please look into the below code

```
function onPreview(){
  let printContents = '';
  const WindowObject = window.open('','PrintWindow','width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes'
  );
  printContents += `<table>
                   <tr>
                     <th>Date</th>
                     <th>ApplicationStatus</th> 
                     <th>SubmittedBy</th>
                   </tr>`;
  filteredDataAfterDate.map(data => {
       printContents += `<tr>
                     <td>${data.Date}</td>
                     <td>${data.ApplicationStatus}</td> 
                     <td>${data.SubmittedBy}</td>
                   </tr>`;
  const htmlData = `<html><body>${printContents}</body></html>`;

  WindowObject.document.writeln(htmlData);
  WindowObject.document.close();
  WindowObject.focus();
  setTimeout(() => {
    WindowObject.close();
  }, 0.5);
};
}
```

apart from this you can create a html table in the html file without pagination and just hide it, take the id or use ViewChild decorator to identify the table and give print.

Comment: Its still showing the data  for the same page i am in .

I need to print all the records irrespective of pagination and currentPage .

Comment: PrintContent ID is still contain only the table data which in the UI (i..e the page i am in )>

In my HTML i have done the Pagination (Please have a look )
@Sijil

Comment: If you want to print the complete table it will be better to generate the complete table inside this function. I have edited the page please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your help . 

But actually i need a  UI to be like when we click clt+P(to print the page) and that page should contain all the data which is filtered .

Not another window with no print option with data . :(